# Why isn't Twitter-bootstrap on rails not allowing background image?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

There are so many duplicates of my question, but as you will see my case is pretty special.

As I was searching for answers,  I found this solutions :

```
background: url('background1.jpg')  no-repeat center center fixed;
```

And it worked, but the funny thing is that it only works for `background1` , when I point it at another file  *(basically, I change `background1` with another picture's name that is in the directory*)  , only white becomes my background.

I even duplicated this `background1` and named it something else, and it did not work.

Why would it work for one picture , and others not? And why wouldn't it work for the same picture after renaming it ?

---

Additional details :

I used `assets/images/` and it did not work, so I switched to `public/images` and that was the first time it worked, but for the other pictures, it does not seem to do it.

Comment: It would be helpful if you put it into context with code. When you say point it at another file, do you mean another image? So that same div with another image? Or another div with another image. Clarify please. And post code

Comment: When I say i point it at another file, I mean I chose another picture to be my background. I'll make an update so it's clear to everybody. Sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using sass and your image has directory structure assets/images/pic.png then try:

```
background: image-url('pic.png')  no-repeat center center fixed;
```

`image-url` will make appropriate path for your assets, checkout [**`rails asset pipeline`**](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#css-and-sass)

**Update:**

You are not using rails asset pipeline, if you look at docs it says

`Asset pipeline concatenate assets, which can reduce the number of requests that a browser makes to render a web page. Web browsers are limited in the number of requests that they can make in parallel, so fewer requests can mean faster loading for your application.`

Hence i will recommend you to use it. For that first *you need to put your images inside **assets/images** folder.*

Secondly we generally use application.css for requiring other stylesheets so i would recommend you to make a new stylesheet, lets assume style.css.scss with directory structure like **app/assets/stylesheets/style.css.scss**

After that require this file inside your application.css by

```
*= require style
```

or if you have `*= require_tree .` in your application.css then it'll require it automatically and inside your style.css.scss file you can have

```
background: image-url('pic.png')  no-repeat center center fixed; # image-url helper will automatically make the required path for your image
```

Comment: Not really, not working. Should it be 'png' ?

Comment: @TECHPUSHTA can you tell me the exact location of your image? and is your css file named .css.scss?

Comment: the `application` stylesheet is `.css` , and the location was in `public/images`, due to the fact that it was in `assets/images/` and my app couldn't find it.

Comment: Oh , sorry, It was just a stupid typo in the name of my picture, it's actually working! :) thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the update, I'll be sticking to what you said.

Comment: Oh great so some moderator deleted my comment. Someone can downvote my answer and i can't even ask why he/she downvoted it lol

Comment: @Mandeep I'd imagine it's bcause you don't actually answer the question, as the OP admitted it's a typo and probably only accepted your answer because it was the only answer on the question. But I wouldn't worry about the votes here. This will all be deleted in due time and then none of it will count towards your reputation anyways.

Comment: Neither the case for downvoting my question, I tried to upvote you again and it miraculously went down, i reclicked and went back to 0. .... No but it was a typo after using you Solution, and not before , So it counts as answer.

Comment: @animuson well if you would have looked at his comments he was using a wrong approach. He was putting his images inside public folder and yeah btw while answering his question i didn't know that "it was a typo." Btw i'm not worried about votes here i was just curious enough to find out why someone would have downvoted it

Comment: **It was a typo, AFTER USING YOUR SOLUTION, AND NOT WRITING IT CORRECTLY. Which means the problem existed not because of the typo, but before I even attempted rewriting the stuff I had.**